# (Android Studio) Suggest variable names over external classes in quick complete?

Tags: android, android-studio

In the following scenario Im looking to quickly autocomplete `datastore`, but Android Studio still suggests 2 other options above it. Usually its even more, depending on the variable name.

**Is it possible to make it prioritize locally declared variables over external classes, so that I get datastore suggested first in the example picture, rather than Datastore, DataOutputStream (classes), and then datastore (variable)?**

*For reference, this is the popup that comes up when you type data and press CTRL + Space (Windows) in Android Studio.*

[image: Autocomplete suggestions]

Comment: Did you found a solution? I experience the same and want to see the local variable first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't see what you have typed on the editor before pressing *CTRL + Space*, but if you type "*datast*" it will prioritize the local variable. If you type "*Datast*" Android Studio prioritizes the class named `Datastore`.

This happens because it is a programming convention to always capitalize the fist letter of a class name.

Comment: I believe I had typed in "datast", and your description is correct - but this isnt the behavior Im seeing. I would expect the local variable (#3 in picture) to be the first one and not classes that match the query.